# how to extract numeric values from jpg file using OCR

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, ocr

I have created the below code and executed:

```
Ocr.setUp();
Ocr ocr = new Ocr();
ocr.startEngine("eng", Ocr.SPEED_FASTEST);
String s = ocr.recognize(theImage, Ocr.RECOGNIZE_TYPE_ALL, Ocr.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PLAINTEXT);
ocr.stopEngine();

Output:
Result: L‘i
L‘L’Ui l
```

Actually the image only contains the numeric values. Is it possible to extract only numeric value by using above code?

I have 1234 numeric value displayed in jpg file, I just want to print that numeric value in o/p console. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a few technology-independent observations about your code.

1. "SPEED_FASTEST" indicates your preference for fast OCR.  Fast is the opposite of High-quality.  You either get speed or quality.  If the image is clear - no problem, but if the image is less than perfect, Quality mode will have more algorithms to deal with defects.
2. Nowhere in your code it is specified that you constrain the character set to digits only. If you do not indicate the language or character set, then usually by default the entire English character set is used. See my response on this post here: [OCR why not find only character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850483/ocr-why-not-find-only-character/33862451#33862451)
3. Typically if you post a sample image along with your question and code, contributors can give you better advice.

Comment: I don't have any privilege to upload the picture right here. But I can tell you how it could be. The picture is similar to logo and It contains some numeric characters. Could you please tell me any solution It would be highly thank full.

Comment: Implementing my two suggestions below will resolve your issue.  Alternatively, switch to a different OCR technology that has these controls out of box for less implementation hustle.